# How can i able to handle two id's (1 jquery id and 1 vue js id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I need to include a sliding for my products for that i am using jquery id and for displaying of items i am using vue js? So, how can I able to manage this two..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function() {

          $("#flexiselDemo1").flexisel({ 
...............................................

});
}
<script>

<ul id="flexiselDemo1">
            <li>
                <a href="details.php"><img src="images/f0.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</li>
<li>
........................
```

This is how my static file looks like and is working fine.

So, to make dynamic i include vue js to display data.. And now my file looks as

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({ 
    el: '#fe' , 
    data: { 
      data: {}, 
    }, 
    mounted() { 

        $(window).load(function() {

          data("mycustomname").flexisel({
                visibleItems: 5,
                animationSpeed: 1000,
                autoPlay: true,
                autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                pauseOnHover: false,
                enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                    portrait: { 
                        changePoint:480,
                        visibleItems: 2
                    }, 
                    landscape: { 
                        changePoint:640,
                        visibleItems: 3
                    },
                    tablet: { 
                        changePoint:800,
                        visibleItems: 4
                    }
                }
            });
            });
       var self = this;

              $.ajax({
          url: ',
          data: {
                      },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (e) { 
            if (e.status == 1) { 
              self.data = e.data; 
              console.log(e.data) 
            }
          }
        });
        console.log(lat);
      }
      function error(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

So, when I display my html codes becomes

```
<div class="review-slider" id="fe">

            <ul id="flexiselDemo1" data-mycustomname="flexisel">
                <div v-for="row in data">
            <li>{{row.name}}</li>
</div>
                </ul>
</div>
```

When I do this way id="flexiselDemo1" doesnot works and layout is completely changing.. So, can anyone please help me to manage this situation?? I am a beginner in js and vue js.. Please have a help on this side..

Comment: is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>If change in ID will break your code why not use data attributes, its totally meant for situations like this.Modify your markup:</strike>

Add className to `ul` tag:

```
<ul id="flexiselDemo1" class="flexis1">
```

In your javascript replace `$("#flexiselDemo1")` with

```
$(".flexis1#flexiselDemo1")
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: this is coming sir

Comment: <div class="review-slider" id="fe">
<ul id="flexiselDemo1" data-mycustomname="flexisel">                          
   <div v-for="row in data">
   <li> </li> </ul> <div></div>

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  new Vue({ 
    el: '#fe' , 
    data: { 
      data: {}, 
    }, 
    mounted() { 

     $(window).load(function() {
   
    data("mycustomname").flexisel({ .............................................................

Comment: this is how i changed